# Split vector into new smaller size vectors

Tags: c++, stdvector

## Problem

I have vector `V = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}` and suppose I want to create `N` new vectors from this large vector.

Example : `N = 3` means it will split the vector by the largest available size i.e. `4-4-3`

`v1 = {1,2,3,4}`

`v2 = {5,6,7,8}`

`v3 = {9,10,11}`

## Code

```cpp
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++) v.push_back(i);   

// Function here to set boundaries ???
N = 3;
v.size()/N % N
//
std::vector<int> v1(v.begin(), v.begin()+3);
std::vector<int> v2(v.begin()+4, v.begin()+7);
std::vector<int> v3(v.begin()+8, v.begin()+11);
```

## Want to Achieve

1. Function that does automatic creation of the vectors by itself so I don't want to manually create `v1,v2,v3` if it is possible.
2. And how I can write the boundary checking algorithm ?

Comment: perhaps you could use a std::span<T>

Comment: Before you go any further please understand how iterator ranges work in C++. Your code should be `std::vector<int> v1(v.begin(), v.begin()+4); std::vector<int> v2(v.begin()+4, v.begin()+8); std::vector<int> v3(v.begin()+8, v.begin()+11);` Your version leaves gaps in the elements copied to the new vectors.

Comment: Consider a middle target: write come code that creates a `vector<vector<int>>` that contains the three vectors you now call `v1`, `v2` and `v3`.

Comment: What does "split the vector by the largest available size" mean? Would having three vectors of size 5, 3, and 3 be an acceptable output?

Comment: @Telescope yes it is possible but I prefer them to be equal sized possible

Comment: There might be something in `range-v3` for this, maybe `chunk`, but whatever it is doesn't seem to have made it into C++20. Maybe next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is to build a `vector` of `vector` to collect the different arrays.

To control the boundaries, one possibility is first to calculate the maximum size of these arrays,
and then to manage two indices, one `ibegin` corresponding to the beginning of a subarray, and one `iend` corresponding to the end of the same subarray.

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<int>> split (const std::vector<int>& v, int Nsplit) {
    int n = v.size();
    int size_max = n / Nsplit + (n % Nsplit != 0);
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> split;
    for (int ibegin = 0; ibegin < n; ibegin += size_max) {
        int iend = ibegin + size_max;
        if (iend > n) iend = n;
        split.emplace_back (std::vector<int>(v.begin() + ibegin, v.begin() + iend));
    }
    return split;
}

int main() {
     std::vector<int>Arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11};
     int Nsplit = 3;
     auto ans = split (Arr, Nsplit);
     
    for (auto &v: ans) {
        for (auto& i: v) {
            std::cout << i << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to store ans in different vectors ?

Comment: In the general case, you don't know in advance the number of vectors. How to define them? If all sizes are known in advance, and you need to define `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, then you need one line for each created vector, as you did, with a control of the bounds as in the `split` function

Comment: Shall I define each vector as sized size_max and then use push_back ?

Comment: Here, you don't need to set the size explicitely. The size is set implicitely with the construction method.

Answer (score 1):

You get get the i-th chunk of `vec` if you divide into `n` chunks like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::span<T> get_chunk(std::vector<T> const & vec, std::size_t n, std::size_t i)
{
  assert(i < n);
  std::size_t const q = vec.size() / n;
  std::size_t const r = vec.size() % n;
  
  auto begin = vec.begin() + i * q + std::min(i, r);
  auto end = vec.begin() + (i + 1) * q + std::min(i + 1, r);
  
  return std::span<T>(begin, end);
}
```

If you don't / can't use `std::span`, just replace it with `std::vector` or use `begin` and `end`-iterators directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Function that does automatic creation of the vectors by itself so I don't want to manually create v1,v2,v3 if it is possible.

What could be a data structure than can hold N number of objects? How about an array? But you might want the size to be determined at runtime. How could you create an array with runtime size? Use a vector! In conclusion, write a function that creates a vector of vectors.

Note that instead of having separate vectors, it might be more efficient to keep the original vector intact, and use a vector of `std::span` (prior to C++20 you can use a non-standard implementation of the same concept) pointing to the subranges.